# window.opener not set after a gui.Window.open()

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

I'm currently building an app with node-webkit and experiencing some trouble with opening new window.

Basically what happens in my app is :

- Open splash.html ( a splash screen )

  - Open the main application ( main.html) with gui.Window.open() but hide it
  - On 'loaded' event, close first window ( splash.html ) and show main.html
- In the app i can compose an email which creates a new window ( composer.html )

  - User click the compose button -> open the composer with gui.Window.open()
- The compose window rely on the main window for it's logic, the main window is accessed with window.opener

This works really fine using a regular browser, but when I bundle it inside node-webkit, window.opener is mostly undefined. I say mostly because sometimes ( ~10% ) the opener is set in the compose window. 
I tried to figure out what was wrong but googling on this subject didn't really helped me.

The things I tried :

- setting the window opener to the current window after opening it => Fail
- going down to the first opened window ( the one defined in the package.json ) to call the open() => Fail

If anyone has any hints on how to solve this, it would be greatly appreciated. I'll be happy to give more details if required.

[EDIT]

Here is the relevant code :

First window ( splash screen ), opened by the package.json

```
<html>
  <script>
  var gui = require('nw.gui');
  var config = require('./config.json');
  gui.App.clearCache();
  var nwWin = gui.Window

  var appWin = nwWin.open(config.url, {
    title : 'MyApp',
    show : false,
    toolbar : false,
    frame : false,
    icon : 'favicon.png',
    width : 1000,
    height : 600,
    min_width : 1000,
    min_height : 400,
    position : 'center'
  });

  appWin.on('loaded', function () {
    appWin.show();
    appWin.focus();
    appWin.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    appWin.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
    nwWin.get().close();
  })
  </script>

  <body>
    <img src="logo.png" />
  </body>

</html>
```

Lots of things in the application but here is the code to open the email composer :

```
NWDesktop.prototype.openAppWindow = function (type, url, title) {
    var appWin = nwWin.open(url, {
      position: 'center',
      toolbar: false,
      frame: true,
      title: title,
      icon: 'favicon.png'
    });
  };
```

In the opened window, window.opener is mostly = undefined.

Comment: Can you share your code?  A simple experiment shows window.opener working OK for me.  If you could provide code that's working in the browser but not in node-webkit, I might be able to help, otherwise it's pretty tricky.

Comment: Added code, just tell me if you need more. In a basic test I also get window.opener defined, and since it sometime happends with my code I suspect some kind of race condition or something but can't figure it out right now.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing the problem.  Can you post a complete test case that shows the problem?

Comment: I think the reazon is you close the opener window and then you ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change a little thing:

First in your splash screen:

```
appWin.on('loaded', function () {
    appWin.show();
    appWin.focus();
    appWin.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    appWin.setAlwaysOnTop(false);

    nwWin.get().hide();

  })
```

Now, window.opener its not null or undefined and you can make wherever you want.

Other things that I make was listener the appWin windows events so, kill the main process of nw when the user close the windows.

Like this:

```
appWin.on('close',function(){
            console.log('CLOSE');
            gui.App.quit();
        });
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have a similar problem and this doesn't fix it. In my case, the result of `gui.Window.open()` is `undefined`, even though the window is created.